# Cronjob for reboot not working

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, cron

I am trying crontab but crontab for email is not working.However, I want that crontab runs a shell script and that shell script runs a python script.

One crontab I tried is

```
* * * * * echo " This is current date and time $(date)"
```

but this is not getting printed on screen. I don't understand what is wrong I am doing.

Comment: What does this have to do with Oracle?

Comment: Sorry didn't saw that tag.

Comment: Don't post code or diagnotics as images. The version of Linux is hardly relevant here anyway. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `cron` tag info](/tags/cron/info) has a faily detailed troubleshooting section. But if you can't send mail at all, why do you think this is a `cron` issue??

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

for sending the email form this command.

```
echo " This is a message " | mailx -s "Subject" mymail@email.com
```

you need to make sure port 25 is open on your system.
you can use the mailq command for check email in the queue on your system.
you can check local port is open or not from

```
telnet localhost 25
nc localhost 25
```

Comment: Hi @himanshubhati : use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. For more info see  and [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Comment: Port 25 inbound doesn't need to be open for outbound mail to work. The OP does nothing to reveal when or how they configured email so they probably never did.

Comment: I just want that I am able to use the cronjob for once. I am quite new to it.Please at least suggest me a simple script which I can try and learn.

Comment: @himanshu can you please tell me what are the dependencies to send mail from crontab?

Comment: i think you have to install mailx ( yum install -y mailx for centos/apt-get install mailx for ubuntu). this pakg allow you to send the email from the system from mail command.  ones the above pakg is installed please try to run mail command to test send mail. (echo "Your message" | mail -s "Message Subject" email@address) . if you still face some issue you check the log (tail /var/log/sendmail)